# C macro inside string in sprintf

Tags: c, macros, padding, printf

I use macro for formatted string copy. Example is given below. Code given bellow tries to pad null characters in remaining portion of string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN     10
#define str(x)  #x

void main() {
    char a[LEN];
    int b = 3445;

    sprintf(a, "%-"str(LEN)"d", b);     // I want "%-10d" here
    printf("|%s|", a);
}
```

when I compile it with `gcc -Wall prog.c` it gives following warnings.

```
warning: format ‘%LE’ expects argument of type ‘long double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

This means that macro is not substituted properly. Can anybody help me here what is wrong here.

Comment: This will pad with blank space. Can we pad '\0' instead of space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to evaluate the argument to `str` once more to see the 10 inside the string

```
#define LEN     10
#define str_(x)  #x
#define str(x)  str_(x)
```

the way you did it, the argument to `str` is stringyfied directly, thus the `LEN` arrived in the format.