# Sprintf: pad with '\0' character instead of space

Tags: c, null, printf, padding

Related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512658/c-macro-inside-string-in-sprintf): the following code

```
sprintf(buffer, "%-16s%-224s%-8s%-8s", "set", "ravi", "26", "60");
```

...pads blank space. I need to pad with `'\0'` character instead of space.  Can this be achieved?

Comment: You do it easily with only sprintf It 's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with the following loop:

```
int i;
sprintf(buffer, "%-16s%-224s%-8s%-8s", "set", "ravi", "26", "60");
for (i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i++)
{
     if (buffer[i] == ' ') buffer[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: So you mean there is no direct solution to this. We have to achieve it manually

Comment: Correct. Alternatively you could change the sprintf function, but i do not recommend that, at all.